# Codeigniter validation error showing inside html comment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm very fresher to Codeigniter and going smoothly my practice.I've a strange problem in my Codeigniter application. I'm using form validation in codeigniter in my application. Actually the validation is working , but validation error come with html comment. I'm really frestrating in two days because I'm unable to identify the issue. The problem is with AJAX response also.

*I'm going to showing a sample. Lets look here*

**Controller**

```
function isDMRefNo_exist() {
    $availstatus = $this->FD_Model->isDMRefNo_exist($_POST['dmrefno']);
    if ($availstatus) {
        echo '<label class="text-danger"  ><span><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> This Reference number already exists.</span></label>';
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="item form-group disp">
    <label for="exampleInputName2 " class="t1">Deposit Reference Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="depositmasterrefnum" name="depositrefnum" required class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" style="text-transform:uppercase" placeholder="Reference Number" maxlength="15">
    <span id="dmrefnoexist_result"></span>
</div>
```

Here is the Ajax request

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#depositmasterrefnum').on('blur', function () {
            var dmrefno = $('#depositmasterrefnum').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Masters/DepositMaster/isDMRefNo_exist",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    dmrefno: dmrefno
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#dmrefnoexist_result').html(data);

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The ajax response is getting through `$( '#dmrefnoexist_result' ).html( data );`

But the output is

[image]

```
<!--<label class="text-danger"  ><span><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> This Reference number already exists.</span></label>-->
```

I'm temporarily resolving this issue by adding end of the comment tag('-->') in the returned result.

Means like this - >

```
echo '--><label class="text-danger"  ><span><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> This Reference number already exists.</span></label>';
```

This is case also in form error displaying.

Please help me to fix this issue.

[image]

Comment: post your view where you have your line with `<span id="dmrefnoexist_result">`

Comment: show me ajax response

Comment: @sintakonte -  See my updated question.

Comment: @Rameshwar- It is in the question.

Comment: Post your ajax response.

Comment: looks somewhat strange - before the line `$( '#dmrefnoexist_result' ).html( data );` type in `console.log(data);` - take a look @the console and post the output

Comment: Output is `<!--<label class="text-danger"  ><span><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> This Reference number already exists.</span></label>`

Comment: Make sure your `FD_Model` 's `isDMRefNo_exist()` have not any echo or print

Comment: You have something else funky going on, as I got your code working and I cannot see how you are getting <!-- in your response! If you use Firefox or Chrome Press F12 to bring up the developer tools and observe the console messages... What do you see?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that will generate html comments.

Comment: What is curious and leads me to believe you are doing other things is that the message is defined as "This Reference number already exists." yet you show at the end of your question a string that is clearly generated by `validation_errors()`

Comment: @Alex -  Sir, I've this problem on both 'showing codeigniter validation errors' and 'Ajax response'. As you said there is no code that generates html comments. That is what I'm looking for these days. Can you help with any RDS?

Comment: Do a search for `<!--` in application